# ZoomToExtent OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

OpenLayers 2 had a very useful `map.zoomToExtent(extent)` feature.  Is there something similar in OpenLayers 3? I can get the extent of interest with `source.getExtent()`, but I can't figure out how to apply that extent as a "zoom level".

Comment: have you tried http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.control.ZoomToExtent.html

Comment: @sfletche That turned out to be the right answer.  If you want to change your comment to an answer I'll select it so you can get awesome internet points.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Going off the function sfletche linked to:

```
var extent = source.getExtent();
map.getView().fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());
```

**EDIT July 23, 2013**

Apparently `fitExtent` is deprecated. Should be `ol.View.fit`, so something linke this (untestesd):

```
var extent = source.getExtent();
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
```

Comment: thanks for the credit @tylerdewitt.  I was too slow to respond, so I'll give you some internet points instead.  :)

Comment: View's fitExtent() seems to be deprecated in 3.4

Comment: It is replaced with [`ol.View.fit`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit) in 3.7.

Comment: map.getSize() is optional, it's the default value.

Comment: Hi there. I am trying with `this.olmap.getView().fit(ext, size, [0, 0, 0, 0], true, false, 0, 15, 2000); ` to make the zoom smooth and animated. And its still not smooth or animated. Any ideas? Thanks (this is OL5)

Comment: @slevin know this is old but you'll probably need view.animate() with example at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html and docs at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#animate

Answer (score 4):

With OpenLayers 4.x this is still a valid solution:

```
map.getView().fit(source.getExtent(), map.getSize());
```

Make sure to set the optional second parameter to prevent console errors, if there are no points on the map.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenLayers 4.x, I found the following methods useful:

`map.getView().setCenter([x, y]);
map.getView().setZoom(z);`

where `x`, `y`, `z` are the coordinates where you want to zoom to.