# reproject map extent in openlayers 3

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I want to set an extend on my Openlayers 3.9.0 map.

When the page loads, I want the map to already be centered in that extend, no matter the layers. So I guess I will set an [extend](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.html#.Extent) to the [view](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html), right?

Map contains a single OSM layer like

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(

        {
        attributions: [
          new ol.Attribution({
            html: 'All maps &copy; ' +
                '<a href="http://www.opencyclemap.org/">OpenCycleMap</a>'
          })
        ]            
      }             

    ),
    opacity: 0.8,
    brightness: 0.8
});
```

Then I set the view

```
var center = ol.proj.transform([21.54967, 38.70250], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    var view = new ol.View({
        center: center,
        zoom: 6,
        extent: [2297128.5,4618333.0 , 2459120.25,4763120.0]
    });
```

And then the map

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [layer],
        view: view,     
    });
```

I used my extend in an older project, with `EPSG 900913`. So to convert the extend from `900913` to default Openlayers 3 `3857` I went here [here](http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/) and I put
`2297128.5, 4618333` that convereted to `2297128.5,4618333.0`

and then

`2459120.25, 4763120`that convereted to `2459120.25,4763120.0`

my two problems

1- the converted coords look similar. Did I do something wrong?

2- the map is centered ok, but not zoomed in the extend. The coords define a county in Greece and the map does not zoom there, I see the whole Greece, along with Turkey and Italy.

What I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: don't forget to give some feedback!

Comment: So choose an answer as correct and finish this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several issues:

- The extent `[2297128.5,4618333.0, 2459120.25,4763120.0]`  seems to be in `EPSG 3857` already and there is no need to transform it.
- The `extent` option of `ol.View` is experimental and does not seem to work well.  You can do the following to set the bounding box (after you declare `map`):

  `var extent = [2297128.5, 4618333.0, 2459120.25, 4763120.0];
  view.fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());`
- The initial zoom in your example was due to the zoom level set on the view (`zoom: 6`).  Using `fitExtent()` should override the initial zoom level. You can remove the `zoom`, `center` and  `extent` options from your view declaration.

By the way, regarding the http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/ site, it seems that you have to specify `EPSG:4326` instead of `EPSG:900913` for the input coordinate, for the transformation to work correctly.

**Note**: `ol.View.fitExtent()` was renamed to `ol.View.fit()` in OpenLayers v3.7.0

Answer (score 5):

Thanks everyone. What I did was

Keep the OSM layer as is.

Define the limits of the county. Turns out it was `EPSG 900913`

```
var countyLimits= ol.proj.transformExtent([2297128.5, 4618333, 2459120.25, 4763120], 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:3857');
```

View is now

```
var view = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 6,
    extent : countyLimits,
    maxZoom:20
});
```

map is

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers:[layer],
    view: view
});
```

After the map is defined, fit its view in the limits

```
    map.getView().fit(countyLimits, map.getSize()); 
//get the view of the map and fit it to the limits, according to the map's size
```

`fitExtend` is now deprecated, so I used `fit`. It is experimental , but I guess it will become standard since it replaced `fitExtend`.

Thanks anyway people

Sources

[OL answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682286/zoomtoextent-openlayers-3)

[OL3 API](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit)

Comment: 900913 is an old name for 3857 and is an alias for it in ol, so you actually do not need the transform.  See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40538/what-is-the-difference-between-epsg900913-and-epsg3857  http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.0/apidoc/ol.proj.Projection.html

Answer (score 2):

It can be as easy as:

```
var min = [2297128.5, 4618333.0];
var max = [2459120.25, 4763120.0];
var extent = ol.extent.boundingExtent([min, max]);

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([21.54967, 38.70250]),
        zoom: 3,
        extent: extent
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/zc3uL66q/